# How to validate email in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to validate email field. And I have a regular expression for email

> /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/

In visual studio my code

```
  Email:<br>
        <input type="text" ng-model="Email" id="txtEmail" ng-pattern="/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <span ng-show="myForm.Email.$error.pattern">Please enter valid Email!</span>
        <span ng-show="myForm.Email.$error.required">*</span><br>
```

An error occuring
[image]

Comment: Itr's pretty weird that you are using a Razor view to hold an Angular template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable for pattern.

```
@{
    var pattern = "/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@@[a-z0-9.-]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/";
}

<input type="text" ng-model="Email" id="txtEmail" ng-pattern="@pattern" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required>
```

Answer (score 5):

Email validation is a popular problem and each regex pattern that you will find doesn't cover all the cases. The best way is to try to send any message to this email or you can use System.Net.Mail.MailAddress class

```
        try
        {
            var email = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(value);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            //handle it here
        }
```

Comment: Good idea; how could that be used on the client side.

Comment: @PeterSmith you can opt for well known validation libraries such as jQuery validation or even cobble up your own [Custom Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for both front and back end (link is to Core, but concepts are the same).

Answer (score 3):

You say you are using C# and MVC. You can use the built in validation; the email validation is supported via an attribute on the field in the model class:

```
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "The email address is not valid")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

The attributes are in the namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

The Razor view then needs something like:

```
<div class="control-group">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "editor-label control-label" })
    <div class="editor-field controls">
        @Html.MbrraceTextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "input-xlarge" })
     </div>
</div>
```

There are many variants on the `cshtml` display styles.